# Something like Dedekind-MacNeille completion

Tags: lattice-theory, posets

The [Dedekind–Macneille completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion) of a poset $P$ can be represented as a complete lattice $\widehat P$ consisting of all lower subsets (order ideals) $I$ for which
$I=(I^\uparrow)^\downarrow$, where $X\mapsto X^\uparrow$ is the "all upper bounds" operator and $X\mapsto X^\downarrow$ is the "all lower bounds" operator.

This week, I came across a construction that seems to be related to $\widehat P$: the definition is the same, but I need to change "all upper/lower bounds" to "all **strict** upper/lower bounds". Let us denote these operators by $X\mapsto X^\Uparrow$ and $X\mapsto X^\Downarrow$ and let us denote the system of all lower subsets $I$ of $P$ such that $I=(I^\Uparrow)^\Downarrow$ by $\overline P$.

1. It is clear, that $X\mapsto (X^\Uparrow)^\Downarrow$ is a closure operator, so $\overline P$ is always a complete lattice.
2. Even in very simple cases, $\overline P$ is different than $\widehat P$. For example if $P$ is a complete lattice, then $\widehat P\simeq P$. This is not true for $\overline P$: for the 4-element Boolean algebra $2^2$, $\overline{2^2}$ is a 3-element chain:

[image: The strange completion]

Has anybody come across this strange $\overline P$ "completion"?